# Installing Sentry2 with Laravel4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, cartalyst-sentry

I am trying to install `Sentry2` with `Laravel4` and I've managed to get as far as to include it within the project as a `dependency` however in terms of the database I am a bit lost. On their website they say:

```
Note: The database schema is located under vendor/cartalyst/sentry/schema/mysql.sql
```

And when I go there I see the `sql` file with various different tables, now this is where I am unsure, do I need to write a `migration` for each one of these tables or is there a way I can just run it in order to create the required `tables`?

I'm new to `laravel` so apologies for the question if it is very simplistic. It just seems impractical to have to write a migration for each table when all of the `sql` is contained in this file?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You can just run or import the .sql file to your database.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure you have your database / environments properly configured before running migrations. This may be obvious for some, but it's always worth checking. This means making sure you have the connection details and credentials right inside your `database.php` file, and that it is located in the folder (or root) which will apply to the environment in which you will run the migrations in.

Second, since Sentry has its own migrations, you don't have to write your own. You just need to run the migrations that come with it. Luckily, Laravel has an easy way to do that. Just run this command on your project's root folder:

```
php artisan migrate --package="cartalyst/sentry"
```

All required tables will be created automatically. From there, you can write a seed and start testing...

Alternatively, you can copy the included migrations into your projects own migrations folder. This way you can migrate up and down without having to worry what comes from a package and what doesn't. To do so, just run the `migrate:publish` command.

```
php artisan migrate:publish cartalyst/sentry
```

This is a native functionality of the framework, so you can run both commands above with any package that properly includes migrations.

Finally, run the migrations:

```
php artisan migrate           // Up
php artisan migrate:rollback  // Down
```